# Query string issue when using views_get_view in Drupal

Tags: string, drupal, view

I'm having issues using the `views_get_view` function in Drupal.

If I use the following on a URL such as `/our-people` it works fine but as soon as a query string is added for pages `/our-people?page=27` then it just doesn't load at all.

```
$view = views_get_view('debt_footer_news');
print $view->render($view->vid);
```

Comment: Try adding `$view->build($display_id);` before the render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this to work.

For anyone else who may experience a similar issue it was to do with the Pager options within the view. I had to change the Pager ID from zero to a higher number so it didn't conflict within the ?page= array.